# Is there a way to map or match people's names to religions in R?

Tags: r

I'm working on a paper on electoral politics and tried using this [dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18IBEdyGN8pVipzqpTG9cYkYDq_cBmXHmJL88xNTT_mw/edit#gid=0) to calculate the share of the electorate that each religion,so I created an if() function and a Christian variable and tried to increase the number of Christians by one whenever a Christian name pops up, but was unable to do so. Would appreciate it if you could help me with this

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
Christian=0
if(Sample...Sheet1$V2=="James"){
Christian=Christian+1
}
```

PS
The Output

```
Warning message:
In if (Sample...Sheet1$V2 == "James") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: You’ll find that in many locations your assumptions are completely invalid. For example, in many countries in Western Europe the majority of the population is nonreligious. If somebody’s called James, all you can conclude is that they’re called James. But nothing about their religion. And the same is true for Ahmet, Miriam and Tarjinder.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you are definitely right about the limited generalization that this exercise has especially in Western Europe. That being said in the case of this dataset it is most assuredly so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notwithstanding my comment about the fundamental non-validity of this approach, here’s how you would solve this general problem in R:

1. Generate a lookup table of the different names and categories — this table is independent of your input data:

   ```
   religion_lookup = tribble(
       ~ Name, ~ Religion,
       'James', 'Christian',
       'Christopher', 'Christian',
       'Ahmet', 'Muslim',
       'Mohammed', 'Muslim',
       'Miriam', 'Jewish',
       'Tarjinder', 'Sikh'
   )
   ```
2. `match` your input data against the lookup table (I’m using an input table `data` with a column `Name` instead of your `Sample...Sheet1$V2`):

   ```
   matched = match(data$Name, religion_lookup$Name)
   religion = religion_lookup$Religion[matched]
   ```
3. Count the results:

   ```
   table(religion)
   ```

   ```
   religion
   Christian    Jewish    Muslim      Sikh
           2         5         3         1
   ```

Note the lack of `if`s and loops in the above.

Answer (score 1):

```r
Christian <- sum( Sample...Sheet1$V2=="James" )
```

There goes, don't need the if block.